# No power_usi_disable() on Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, compile

we have an error after compiling the code in arduinouno that is displayed as
error: 'power_usi_disable' was not declared in this scope   in Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno".how to rectify this error. please reply us fast

Answer (score 3):

The Arduino Uno does not have a USI peripheral. Thus, you cannot disable
the power of the (non-existent) USI, and there is no
`power_usi_disable()` function.

Solution: remove the call to `power_usi_disable()` from your code.

**Update**: To answer your *new* question in the comment, `WDTCR` is the
Watchdog Timer Control Register on some AVR chips. On the Uno it is
called `WDTCSR`, because it is a control and status register.

Looks to me like you have downloaded from somewhere a program you do not
understand. That program was written for an ATtiny chip and you are
trying to compile it as-is for an Arduino Uno, which is based on an
(incompatible) ATmega328P. That's not the way to do it: you have to
understand the program and rewrite all the ATtiny specific stuff to fit
the Uno.

Comment: Thank you ,but we have an other error exit status 1
'WDTCR' was not declared in this scope. plz help us

Comment: Check the board selection in the Arduino IDE Tools menu. Also please post source code and compiler warnings/errors.

Comment: @ppsrc: Se amended answer.